# Accessing a mapped list

Tags: python

How do i go about accessing a list after i've mapped it using the map() function in Python? Say if i then want to reuse this list, sort it, edit it in some form etc.

Or maybe my question is more, how do i access a variable declared inside of a function, globally?

My code is here:

```
def list_mapper(number_string):

    newlist = list(map(int, number_string.strip().split()))

    


list_mapper("4 5 4 5 4 5 43 ")


print(newlist)
```

But `newlist` isn't accessible. Is this the correct way to do this or should the code be structured in some other way for me to access it?

Comment: You need to `return` it & put it in a variable.

Comment: newlist is a local variable. cannot be accessed outside the function. Also you havent return anything inside a function.

Comment: such "formatter functions" also work nicely as a `lambda`, e.g. here `list_mapper = lambda s: list(map(int, s.strip().split()))` and then you can call `new_list = list_mapper("4 5 4 5 4 5 43 ")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created the variable `newlist` inside the function `list_mapper`; this means it's only available inside the function. This is an example of *scope*; in this case, the variable is *scoped* to the function and not available outside.

The usual solution to this is to have your function *return* the value you want to use. You can do this like so:

```py
def list_mapper(number_string):
    return list(map(int, number_string.strip().split()))


newlist = list_mapper("4 5 4 5 4 5 43 ")

print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a function, you need to `return` the value you want it to produce:

```
def list_mapper(number_string):

    newlist = list(map(int, number_string.strip().split()))
    return newlist

newlist = list_mapper("4 5 4 5 4 5 43 ")

print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

newlist doesn't exist in the main bloc (you should have an error)
you must return it from list_mapper ans use the return value in main bloc

```py
def list_mapper(number_string):

    newlist = list(map(int, number_string.strip().split()))
    return newlist
    


print(list_mapper("4 5 4 5 4 5 43 "))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return the mapped list.

```
def list_mapper(number_string):

    newlist = list(map(int, number_string.strip().split()))

    return newlist
    


newlist = list_mapper("4 5 4 5 4 5 43 ")


print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `return` the function will return the list,

```
def list_mapper(number_string):

    newlist = list(map(int, number_string.strip().split()))

    
    return newlist

lit=list_mapper("4 5 4 5 4 5 43 ")


print(lit)
```